# ActionView::Template::Error (application.css):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Have problem with

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I changed css to scss everything was working well and after restarting the server error occurred.

[image]

Any idea how to fix it so far all answers on StackOverflow have not been applied.

Comment: could you show your `app/assets/config/manifest.js` ? i guess that when you `changed css to scss everything`, you also change `//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css` to `//= link_directory ../stylesheets .scss`, if you did so, revert `.css` instead of `.scss`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replay. I did the change, and I get still the same error.

Comment: working Thanks 